# How to fetch unique value in liquid file

Tags: shopify

here is my code i tried to fetch only unique value from items variable but I got all value can someone please help to solve this

```
       {% capture items %}
          {% for tag in product.tags %}              
          {%if tag contains 'pair'%} 
          {% assign tag_split = tag  |  remove_first: 'pair::' | split: "::" %}
          {% assign color = tag_split[0]  %} 
             {{color}}
          {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}              
       {% endcapture %}

          {% assign my_array = items | split: ", " %}

          <p>{{ my_array | uniq }} </p>
```

Comment: Can you please share the data you get while processing the tags?

Comment: pair::silver::blue::joory-earring-blue-silver
pair::gold::malachite::joory-earring-malachite-gold
pair::gold::tiger-eye::copy-of-joory-earrings-tiger-eye-gold

pair is prefix value gold is color ,tiger-eye is stone and last one is handle i need to separate theme all and so my values will be only one gold and every value will be unique

Comment: what becomes into items after all splits and replace?

Comment: items shows gold,gold,silver

i need gold,silver

Comment: Okay, the issue is ',' you split with ',' but there is not ',' into string items when capturing

Comment: `{%- assign my_array = items | strip | split:' ' | uniq | join:',' -%}` use like to strip the spaces and then split the string using space and get unique array items

Comment: i have tried this before but my one value is rose gold so it removes gold from rose gold also

Comment: `silver gold gold` this is your item's capture output, you need to add `,` to avoid it.

Comment: `{%- capture items -%}{% for tag in ptags %}{%if tag contains 'pair'%}{% assign tag_split = tag  |  remove_first: 'pair::' | split: "::" %}{% assign color = tag_split[0] %}{{color | prepend: "," }}{% endif %}{% endfor %}{%- endcapture -%}

  {%- assign my_array = items | remove_first:',' | split:',' | uniq | join:',' -%}`

Comment: Try like this and avoid the spaces when writing liquid code, and it works well

Comment: can you please explain why it is necessary to write in one line 
when i write in multiple lines it didnt work but when i write in one  line it works perfectly

Comment: When you write the code inside the editor, lot of new lines and whitespaces are added automatically, so you need to write the code into a single line or add whitespace remover like this snapshot https://prnt.sc/1wlxmxj

Comment: You can also check the new liquid tag also which is used to write the code inside template theme files [liquid](https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/tags/theme-tags#liquid) https://prnt.sc/1wly77v

Comment: to tag an HTML tag you need to loop the array elements and use the simple HTML or liquid code to wrap the tag inside the HTML element. https://prnt.sc/1wt2hmq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This filter should help you to keep only one elem per value:
https://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/uniq/

Comment: Alice tired but not working

Comment: But I got  right answer from onkar